# How do I find out if a .NET assembly contains unmanaged code?

Tags: .net, assemblies, unmanaged, native

.NET assemblies that contain a mixture of managed and unmanaged code cannot be ILMerged with other assemblies.

How can I verify if a given .NET assembly contains purely managed code, or a mix of managed and unmanaged code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run the [PEVerify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62bwd2yd(v=vs.100).aspx) tool against your assembly.

PEVerify.exe is installed along with Visual Studio, e.g. this one comes with Visual Studio 2012:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\PEVerify.exe`

Comment: Once you run this utility, how can one tell if it's purely managed code? I just get: "All Classes and Methods in <foo> Verified."

Comment: @DanW: then it's all good. You'll get errors otherwise. If invoked from a script or another program, you can check for a non-zero exit code which indicates errors. You can test this by using the "unsafe" keyword in C#.

Answer (score 10):

As suggested by nobugz, an easier way to see the CLR Flags is using the `corflags` utility, which is part of the .NET 2.0 SDK.

If no options are specified, the flags for the given image are displayed:

```
C:\>corflags Foo.dll
Version   : v2.0.50727
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32
CorFlags  : 9
ILONLY    : 1
32BIT     : 0
Signed    : 1
```

The "ILONLY" bit indicates whether this is a pure managed assemby, or a mixed assembly.

Note that the comment from user 'nobugz' suggests these flags are not guaranteed to be correct, so this method may not be foolproof.

Answer (score 4):

Run ildasm from a Visual Studio Command Prompt as follows:

> ildasm file.exe /headers /noil /text

Towards the end of the output you will see the following:

> // ----- CLR Header:
>   // Header size:                        ...
>   // Major runtime version:              ...
>   // Minor runtime version:              ...
>   // ...
>   // Flags:                              0x00000000

If Flags has the lowest bit set (e.g. 0x00000001) then the assembly is pure CLR; if not (e.g. 0x00000000) then the assembly is mixed mode. Note that other flags may be present, so it's only the lowest bit you're interested in (so if the last digit is 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, b, d or f then it's pure CLR).

(Edit: You can also run ildasm graphically, open the executable file in question, and choose Headers from the View menu to see the same information.)

Comment: Not a slam-dunk afaik, the C++/CLI compiler/linker doesn't set this bit right, even if you compile with /clr:pure.  Corflags.exe shows this too.

Answer (score 2):

Improving on the answer provided above Wim...

1. Locate your "PEVerify.exe" - you have it if you have VS installed.- COPY THE FULL PATH TO THE PEVerify.exe file, your path will be different - - Here's an example: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\PEVerify.exe
2. Open Visual Studio Command prompt (don't "Run as Administrator")
3. Type in: `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools`
4. your command prompt should now be this long text instead of just C:\ or something....it will point to the path of where PEVerify.exe is located.
5. Now type in: `peverify "your full path to your dll you want to check`  - THen Press Enter - Here is my example : peverify "G:\TestFolder\My_Managed_OR_Unmanaged.dll"
6. After you press Enter and you get a message as below, its 100% managed dll - All Classes and Methods in My_Managed_OR_Unmanaged.dll Verified."

Answer (score 1):

To get the PE flags from C#, use the System.Reflection API: http://www.example8.com/category/view/id/6027

...

```
Assembly a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Module m = a.ManifestModule;

PortableExecutableKinds peKinds;
ImageFileMachine imageFileMachine;
m.GetPEKind(out peKinds, out imageFileMachine);

if ((peKinds & PortableExecutableKinds.ILOnly) != 0)
```

...

Answer (score 0):

I'll have to double check this but I am pretty sure you can find that out with Reflector by redgate.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a good idea - it is lots of work to dig all methods of an assembly

Comment: How? I can't find anything in Reflector 5.1.6.0 regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

ILMerge only merges managed assemblies, [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en), to quote from their download page, '*ILMerge is a utility for merging multiple .NET assemblies into a single .NET assembly*'.

I have not seen an managed assembly merged with a native binary. Technically, you could have them merged per se, by including the unmanaged binary as a embedded resource, but the loading of the embedded resource into memory as a binary code - I have not seen this before. I have tried that technique using memory maps but failed.

The other way of checking is to look in the binary itself, if it has the 15th entry in the data directory, and is non-zero then it is a .NET binary, native binaries do not have this. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817152/detect-whether-the-assembly-was-built-for-net-compact-framework/1817231#1817231) where I posted this answer to a similar question.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use .NET reflection to go through all types and methods in assembly.