# How to migrate assemblies from .Net 3.5 to .Net 4.0?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, assemblies, project-reference

I download a project from github:
https://github.com/HEskandari/FarsiLibrary/zipball/master

I open this with visual studio 2010, This Solution contain a project with name **"FarsiLibrary.WPF.VisualStudio.Design"**, this project contain references to assemblies in .Net 3.5 and visual studio not recognize **Microsoft.Windows.Design.*** assemblies because this assemblies
exist in .Net 3.5.

So when i changing Target Framework to 3.5 unfortunately this changing not reflected and then target framework set again to .Net 4 automatically.

I want to know how to handle it to build without any problem?

Thank.

Comment: Have you installed Framework 3.5 on your machine? I can build solutions targetting both 3.5 and 4 with VS 2010 and I have no problem... Just be sure your 3.5 assemblies don't reference 4.0 assemblies

Comment: Oh, right, i don't install framework 3.5. How to upgrade this without dependency to framework 3.5?

Comment: I think you need to change reference and target assembly Microsoft.Windows.Design.* in extension (not directly in Framework)... but I'm not sure about this. Or you could install Framework 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Run [PEVerify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1946322/1235565) or `corflags` to determine whether `FarsiLibrary.WPF.VisualStudio.Design` is mixed mode or a pure .NET application.

If it is a mixed mode assembly, add this to your app config file:

```
configuration>
   <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
   </startup>
</configuration>
```

Or even better, recompile `FarsiLibrary.WPF.VisualStudio.Design` targetting .NET 4.0.