# How find which dll is causing: "Mixed mode assembly built against version ... cannot be loaded in 4.0 runtime"?

Tags: .net, dll, mixed-mode

There are many questions about "Mixed mode assembly is built against version .. of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime",

E.g. [Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v1.1.4322'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018924/mixed-mode-assembly-is-built-against-version-v1-1-4322)

but I don't see any discussion of **how to find out WHICH referenced dll is the mixed mode assembly that is causing the problem.**

This is happening in an upgrade of an old .NET 3.5 WinForms + XNA desktop app with MANY source files, that references a variety of 3rd-party dlls.  I can't just remove them one at a time, because then the app won't build at all.

NOTE: the project that gives the "Mixed mode .." error during build is a class library, written in VB.

(Upgrading to .NET 4.5.2, as a step towards moving from 32-bit to 64-bit.)

I haven't successfully gotten rid of the error message, even after adding `useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"`, but rather than expend more time figuring out why that doesn't work, I'd like to know which dll it is - I suspect I will want to replace the offending library with some newer solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this as follows.

1. Visual Studio 2015 - Tools / Options / Projects and Solutions / **Build and Run:**
   **MSBuild project build output verbosity:

   Detailed.**
2. From Output (Build), copy paste all the text into Notepad++. Find very long line with **"sgen.exe"**.  This is worthwhile in itself, as it **shows all referenced dlls, with their full paths**.
3. Run Command prompt, try variations of that "sgen.exe" line, omitting various `/reference ...` parameters.

RESULT:
Most references could be included, without causing "mixed mode" error.
All the third-party dlls I had suspected do not cause this error.
Discovered the problem was the **Microsoft.DirectX.* dlls**!

FIX:
Switch to `SharpDX`.
Change references from `Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D` to `SharpDX.Direct3D11` (or `SharpDX.DirectX9`, etc.)
(I was going to do this later, to go to 64-bits; had not realized I needed to do this just to get to .NET 4.5+)

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping there is a more direct way to find more details from the complaining message; but if that is not possible, then one answer is to run something (e.g. `Peverify.exe`) against all the dlls, and examine the results:

[How do I find out if a .NET assembly contains unmanaged code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946322/how-do-i-find-out-if-a-net-assembly-contains-unmanaged-code)

**RESULT:**
**Was not helpful.**
Most of the dlls appear to be a mix of managed and unmanaged, so this isn't narrowing down the problem. Specifically, this approach is not telling me whether all these mixed dlls are problematic, or only one or a few of them.